# Objective-C iOS 14: Setting polarity to stereo yields omnidirectional. Following Apple docs

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios14, avaudiosession

I'm following along with [this doc from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones?language=objc) on how to implement stereo capture. After setting the polarity, it's still coming back as omnidirectional instead of stereo. All the outErrors from the setters are nil, and all of the individual setters are yielding YES (success) results. So, everything is as expected except for the final check that the polarity is set to "stereo." That one is failing.

```
if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
    BOOL wasStereoConfigurationSuccessful = [self _configureStereoCapture:outError];
    NSLog(@"wasStereoConfigurationSuccessful=%@", wasStereoConfigurationSuccessful ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}

- (BOOL)_configureStereoCapture:(NSError **)outError {
    BOOL wasBuiltInMicConfigurationSuccessful = [self _configureBuiltInMic:outError];
    if (!wasBuiltInMicConfigurationSuccessful) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL wasMicInputDirectionalityConfigurationSuccessful = [self _configureMicrophoneInputDirectionality:outError];
    if (!wasMicInputDirectionalityConfigurationSuccessful) {
        return NO;
    }
    return outError == nil;
}

- (BOOL)_configureBuiltInMic:(NSError **)outError {
    // Enabling stereo requires either AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
    BOOL canStereoBeEnabled = [_audioSession.category isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord] || [_audioSession.category isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord];

    if (!canStereoBeEnabled) {
        return NO;
    }

    // Get the set of available inputs. If there are no audio accessories attached, there will be
    // only one available input -- the built in microphone.
    NSArray<AVAudioSessionPortDescription *> *availableMics = [_audioSession availableInputs];
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription *builtInMic = nil;
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *mic in availableMics) {
        if ([mic.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic]) {
            builtInMic = mic;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (builtInMic == nil) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL wasPreferredInputSetSuccessfully = [_audioSession setPreferredInput:builtInMic error:outError];
    if (!wasPreferredInputSetSuccessfully) {
        return NO;
    }

    return wasPreferredInputSetSuccessfully;
}

- (BOOL)_configureMicrophoneInputDirectionality:(NSError **)outError {

    AVAudioSessionPortDescription *preferredInput = _audioSession.preferredInput;
    NSArray<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription *> *dataSources = preferredInput.dataSources;
    AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription *newDataSource = nil;

    AVAudioSessionOrientation audioSessionOrientation = _AudioSessionOrientation(); // Proprietary C helper

    for (AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription *dataSource in dataSources) {
        if ([dataSource.dataSourceName isEqualToString:audioSessionOrientation]) {
            newDataSource = dataSource;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (newDataSource == nil) {
        *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"class_name" code:0 userInfo:@{@"message" : @"dataSource.dataSourceName does not equal any available AVAudioSessionOrientation."}];
        return NO;
    }

    NSArray<AVAudioSessionPolarPattern> *supportedPolarPatterns = newDataSource.supportedPolarPatterns;
    BOOL isStereoSupported = NO;
    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
        isStereoSupported = [supportedPolarPatterns containsObject:AVAudioSessionPolarPatternStereo];
    }

    if (!isStereoSupported) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL wasPreferredPolarPatternSuccessfullySet = NO;
    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
        wasPreferredPolarPatternSuccessfullySet = [newDataSource setPreferredPolarPattern:AVAudioSessionPolarPatternStereo error:outError];
    }

    if (!wasPreferredPolarPatternSuccessfullySet) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL wasPreferreredDataSourceSuccessfullySet = [preferredInput setPreferredDataSource:newDataSource error:outError];
    if (!wasPreferreredDataSourceSuccessfullySet) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL wasPreferredInputOrientationSuccessfullySet = NO;
    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
        wasPreferredInputOrientationSuccessfullySet = [_audioSession setPreferredInputOrientation:_AudioStereoOrientationFromAudioSessionOrientation(audioSessionOrientation) error:outError];
    }

    if (!wasPreferredInputOrientationSuccessfullySet) {
        return NO;
    }
  
  NSLog(@"error is nil=%@", outError == nil ? @"YES" : @"NO");
  
  NSLog(@"preferredInput=%@", _audioSession.preferredInput);
  
  NSLog(@"preferredDataSource=%@", _audioSession.preferredInput.preferredDataSource);
  
  NSLog(@"selectedPolarPattern=%@", _audioSession.preferredInput.preferredDataSource.selectedPolarPattern);

  return outError == nil;
}
```

This is the printout:

```
error is nil=YES

preferredInput=<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x282e1d470, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone Microphone; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = Bottom>

preferredDataSource=<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x282e1cd60, ID = 1835216946; name = Front>

// *** PROBLEM ***
selectedPolarPattern=Omnidirectional // This should be 'Stereo'

wasStereoConfigurationSuccessful=YES
```

Comment: I am having the same problem on iOS 16 and an iPhone 13. Have you found a solution to this yet?